# Has anyone built gcc 8.2.0 on OpenBSD 6.3?

Tags: gcc, openbsd, gcc8

I am getting the following error when I try to build gcc 8.2.0 on OpenBSD 6.3:

```
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile /home/shane/gcc-8.2.0/host-i386-unknown-openbsd6.3/gcc/xgcc -B/home/shane/gcc-8.2.0/host-i386-unknown-openbsd6.3/gcc/ -B/opt/gcc-8.2.0/i386-unknown-openbsd6.3/bin/ -B/opt/gcc-8.2.0/i386-unknown-openbsd6.3/lib/ -isystem /opt/gcc-8.2.0/i386-unknown-openbsd6.3/include -isystem /opt/gcc-8.2.0/i386-unknown-openbsd6.3/sys-include    -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../.././libatomic/config/x86 -I../.././libatomic/config/posix -I../.././libatomic -I.    -march=i486 -mtune=i386 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -Werror   -pthread -g -O2 -MT fence.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fence.Tpo -c -o fence.lo ../.././libatomic/fence.c
libtool: compile:  /home/shane/gcc-8.2.0/host-i386-unknown-openbsd6.3/gcc/xgcc -B/home/shane/gcc-8.2.0/host-i386-unknown-openbsd6.3/gcc/ -B/opt/gcc-8.2.0/i386-unknown-openbsd6.3/bin/ -B/opt/gcc-8.2.0/i386-unknown-openbsd6.3/lib/ -isystem /opt/gcc-8.2.0/i386-unknown-openbsd6.3/include -isystem /opt/gcc-8.2.0/i386-unknown-openbsd6.3/sys-include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../.././libatomic/config/x86 -I../.././libatomic/config/posix -I../.././libatomic -I. -march=i486 -mtune=i386 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -Werror -pthread -g -O2 -MT fence.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fence.Tpo -c ../.././libatomic/fence.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fence.o
../.././libatomic/fence.c:26:10: fatal error: stdatomic.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdatomic.h>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[4]: *** [Makefile:491: fence.lo] Error 1
gmake[4]: Leaving directory '/home/shane/gcc-8.2.0/i386-unknown-openbsd6.3/libatomic'
gmake[3]: *** [Makefile:524: all-recursive] Error 1
gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/home/shane/gcc-8.2.0/i386-unknown openbsd6.3/libatomic'
gmake[2]: *** [Makefile:360: all] Error 2
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/shane/gcc-8.2.0/i386-unknown-openbsd6.3/libatomic'
gmake[1]: *** [Makefile:21680: all-target-libatomic] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/shane/gcc-8.2.0'
gmake: *** [Makefile:943: all] Error 2
```

My process:

- Install OpenBSD (using defaults)
- Run syspatch
- Add some packages:

  ```
  # pkg_add wget
  # pkg_add gmp mpfr libmpc
  # pkg_add gmake
  ```
- Get the source:

  ```
  $ wget ftp://ftp.nluug.nl/mirror/languages/gcc/releases/gcc-8.2.0/gcc-8.2.0.tar.gz
  $ tar xzf gcc-8.2.0.tar.gz
  $ cd gcc-8.2.0
  ```
- Build:

  ```
  $ ./configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-8.2.0 --with-gmp=/usr/local --enable-languages=c,c++
  $ gmake
  ```

This also fails with gcc 8.1.0 in a similar way.

I also tried using clang rather than gcc to build, like this:

```
$ CC=cc CXX=c++ ./configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-8.2.0 --with-gmp=/usr/local --enable-languages=c,c++
```

That made no difference, which makes some sense as apparently it is failing in stage 3 (gcc compiling itself again for a final check).

Annoyingly, there *is* a `stdatomic.h` file in the tarball:

```
$ find gcc-8.2.0 -name stdatomic.h                             
gcc-8.2.0/gcc/ginclude/stdatomic.h
```

So I have no idea what I am missing.

Has anyone successfully built this? How?